# How can you make a C compiler assume decimal literals (e.g. 1.23) are float and not double?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

In my source code, if I write 1.23 as a literal, e.g. doThis(1.23), gcc assumes it's a double.

Rather than type doThis((float) 1.23), is there a way to use floats for decimal literals/constants unless otherwise specified in an individual source file?

Mega-bonus points, is there a way that works across (nearly) every C compiler?

Comment: There's no way to do it for all "plain" constants in a source file, as you seem to want. You have to use either a cast or a suffix.

Comment: The suffix works great... I'd completely forgotten about it!

Comment: [Make C floating point literals float (rather than double)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32266864/995714). But note that this is not recommended for most cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the standard way is to write `1.23f`. It works with every C compiler, since it is defined in ISO C99 section *6.4.4.2 Floating constants*. ISO C90 and K&R have similar definitions.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
float fred = 0.37f;
```

Comment: Yoda says: 'Do, or do not.  There is no try'.

Answer (score 2):

try `123.4F` for a float constant

Answer (score 2):

Also gcc has the option -fsingle-precision-constant that tells the compiler to treat constants as single precision.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath