# Make C floating point literals float (rather than double)

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, literals

It is well known that in C, floating point literals (e.g. `1.23`) have type `double`. As a consequence, any calculation that involves them is promoted to double.

I'm working on an embedded real-time system that has a floating point unit that supports only single precision (`float`) numbers. All my variables are `float`, and this precision is sufficient. I don't need (nor can afford) `double` at all. But every time something like

```
if (x < 2.5) ...
```

is written, disaster happens: the slowdown can be up to two orders of magnitude. Of course, the direct answer is to write

```
if (x < 2.5f) ...
```

but this is so easy to miss (and difficult to detect until too late), especially when a 'configuration' value is `#define`'d in a separate file by a less disciplined (or just new) developer.

So, is there a way to force the compiler to treat all (floating point) literals as float, as if with suffix `f`? Even if it's against the specs, I don't care. Or any other solutions? The compiler is gcc, by the way.

Comment: There's `-Wdouble-promotion`, which will at least give you warnings. Combined with `-Wfloat-conversion` should give pretty good coverage.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but it wouldn't be that difficult to write a script to just insert any missing `f`s from FP literals.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688911/compile-c-code-with-float-instead-of-double ?

Comment: Some compilers for embedded systems map double to float and only enable double precision with an option. I don't know if there are something similar in GCC

Comment: @BrettHale That comment is worthy of being an proper answer. I think that getting warnings in this case would be more productive, than some other compiler option that allows programmer to write code that's not compatible with the standard.

Comment: Curious, does the code call any variadic functions such as `printf()` with `float` arguments?

Comment: `but this is so easy to miss` you mean you don't think about floating-point typesafety at all?

Comment: Are relational operators a performance problem? I would think a decent compiler should be able to turn `x > 0.1` and `x >= 1.3` into `x >= 0.1` and `x > 1.3f`, respectively, using the as-if rule [there aren't any floating-point values exactly equal to 0.1 or 1.3, so the senses of `>=` and `>` will change depending upon whether the nearest float is above or below the specified literal].

Comment: @Rahul: no, the types are all set, this is an easy part. It is constants and implicit promotion to double that is a problem.  

@supercat: well, my understanding is that the standard _requires_ any floating point constant (and calculations involving them) to be treated as `double` by default, even say 1.0 which can be represented as `int`, let alone `float`.

However, if I actually use an integer constant (e.g. `if (x < 2)`, where `x` is `float`, then it will only be promoted to `float`. But this doesn't help in most cases.

And yes, performance is a problem with relational operators too.

Comment: @user694733: you are right, but see my comment to Brett's answer.

Comment: @chux: no. `printf()` in particular is so heavy in my library (over 20 KB!) that it almost doesn't fit in the chip, and it is very slow as well.

Comment: replace all `/(\d*\.\d+)(?=[^f])/` with `$1f`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[`-fsingle-precision-constant`](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) flag can be used. It causes floating-point constants to be loaded in single precision even when this is not exact.

Note- This will also use single precision constants in operations on double precision variables.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this flag. This answers my question perfectly - even though, as other suggested, generating warnings would perhaps be more prudent.

Comment: I would use this option wisely! Consider a new developer, just typing `x < 2.5`, everything will be okay. He is likely to miss that specific compiler option which saves his life :-). When he is getting warnings instead (with `-Wdouble-promotion`, `-Wfloat-conversion`), and you use `-Werror` which converts all warnings into errors, he may not directly checkin the code, and might wonder, and learn. But just for release quality, you might want to play safe, and compile it with the specific option (`-fsingle-precision-constant`). Please note this is just a comment.

Answer (score 59):

Use warnings instead: `-Wdouble-promotion` warns about *implicit* float to double promotion, as in your example. `-Wfloat-conversion` will warn about cases where you may still be assigning doubles to floats.

This is a better solution than simply forcing double values to the nearest float value. Your floating-point code is still compliant, and you won't get any nasty surprises if a double value holds a positive value, say, less than `FLT_DENORM_MIN` (assuming IEEE-754) or greater than `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: You are right in general, of course. However, in my specific circumstances `-fsingle-precision-constant` works better. First, my version of GCC (4.4.7) simply doesn't have either of these options. Second, I don't have any tricky constants (apart from NaN), and all calculations must be `float` anyway (this is the whole point). Finally, the supplied chip library generates so many warnings (most of them explicit!) that the useful ones often get buried in the pile...  

And, as I said, I'm not very concerned about strict compliance in this case.

Comment: I, too, believe that it is dangerous to just hide a problem that is in your source code using a command switch. Just consider that your code might be used by someone else five years from now using a new version of the compiler, maybe not having that neat switch. It is much preferable to fix the problems in the source code than to hide them. And about all these warnings... when compiling for production, warnings should be considered errors. -Werror :-)

Comment: there's nothing smart about forcing yourself to write `f` at the end of _every_ number literal,

Comment: @12Me21 : look at the asm output of: `float fn (float x) { return (x * 1.2); }` vs `(1.2f)` - the expression is forced to be evaluated as a double and then converted back to a float. It's not a question of being 'smart'.

Comment: oh I just meant, I feel like -fsingle-precision-constant is a better solution here.
same result with less effort.

Comment: @12Me21 there's also nothing smart about forcing yourself to write `.0` at the end of every integer to ensure it's a floating point and not integer. This is just how ANSI-C works, and arguing against it is a bit of tilting at windmills. If I can write `.0`, it's really no more effort to accept `.0f`.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the defined constants to `(float)` wherever they are used, the optimizer should do its job. This is a portable solution.

```
#define LIMIT 2.5

if (x < (float)LIMIT) ...
```

Comment: Or cast them in the definition, as in #define foo ((float) 1.234)

Comment: @CuriousRabbit: that doesn't address the "a less disciplined (or just new) developer" issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Wunsuffixed-float-constants` flag could be used too, maybe combined with some of the other options in the accepted answer above.  However, this probably won't catch unsuffixed constants in system headers.  Would need to use `-Wsystem-headers` to catch those too.  Could generate a lot of warnings...