# When do C and C++-compilers convert or promote a float to double, implicitly?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, compilation

For an embedded project I'd like to know when does a standard-compliant C-compiler (C99) and C++-compiler (C++11) will most likely implicitly promote a single-float variable/value to double-float.

I'm aware of two cases:

1. literals which are not suffixed with `f`. For example: `3.14`
2. passing a float to function with variadic argument-list (`...`)

Are there any others? What about templates?

The answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266864/make-c-floating-point-literals-float-rather-than-double) are very helpful for me as well - including it here for reference.

Comment: In all operations where the usual arithmetic conversions are used.

Comment: You might want to read about [standard conversions in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast). And [for C as well](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: @Patrick B. As for literals then there is no conversions. It is the definition of the lfloating literal.

Comment: You can't pass a `double` to a template anyway. And the template instantiation will have a concrete function signature.

Answer (score 9):

In C:

A numeric literal with `.` and no suffix, e.g. `3.14`, does not involve any promotion. It is `double` for its entire lifetime.

A float is **promoted** to double if the float is an argument to a function call, and the function being called has no prototype in scope, or the argument corresponds to the ellipsis (`...`) in the prototype in scope.

A float is **converted** to double in any of the following situations:

- The float is an argument to a function call corresponding to a parameter of type `double` in a prototype in scope.
- A binary operator has `double` and `float` as the two argument types. The operators this applies to are: `* / + - < > <= >= == !=`
- The conditional operator has `double` and `float` as the second and third operand (in either order)
- The float is cast to `double`
- The float is assigned to a `double` (including compound assignment)

---

In C++, all of the above cases still apply, except for the cases about no prototype (since C++ requires all function calls to have a prototype in scope).

There is a new case: the [standard conversion sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) which is too complicated to summarize briefly. But as an example, this C++ code contains an implicit conversion from `float` to `double` :

```
class T { public: T(double dummy) {} };
void foo(T); 
foo(3.14f); // Conversion sequence: float->double->T
```

I'm not sure if this is an exhaustive list for C++ though.

Comment: C++ has no "functions without prototypes" (i.e. In C++, `void foo()` is a function without arguments). Other than that, these cases all apply to C++ as well.