# One float variable shows expected result but other doesn't

Tags: c

```
float a = 0.5;
float b = 0.7;
printf("%f",a);
printf("\n");
printf("%f",b);
if(a == .5)
  printf("\nOK\n");
else
   printf("NOTOK\n");

if(b == .7)
  printf("OK");
else
  printf("NOTOK");
```

It seems that output should be OK for both a and b but the output is OK for a but NOTOK for b. Why?

Comment: You've declared `b` as `float`, which is smaller than the default floating point type (`double`), so you're comparing `(float) 0.7` to `(double) 0.7)`.  Since `0.7` cannot be exactly represented, they are not the same.  Try replacing all your `float` variables with `double`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal

Comment: Another option [Make C floating point literals float (rather than double)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266864/make-c-floating-point-literals-float-rather-than-double)

Answer (score 1):

For `float` numbers you need to represent it as example: `0.5f` .Below example is tested and working fine.

```
float a = 0.5;
float b = 0.7;
printf("%f",a);
printf("\n");
printf("%f",b);

if(a == 0.5f && b == 0.7f)
{
  printf("\nOK\n");
}
else
{
   printf("NOTOK\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.5` and `.7` are constants and they are translated to double. Add "f" symbol at the end to tell compiler that `.5f` and `.7f` are floats.

```
if(a == .5f)
  printf("\nOK\n");
else
   printf("NOTOK\n");

if(b == .7f)
  printf("OK");
else
  printf("NOTOK");
```